# How to solve the FMU error: 'fmi2SetupExperiment'

Tags: matlab, fmi

The issue is that I was testing the fmu file using Simulink (fmu was generated by GT, fmi 2.0), it worked well on one pc, but an error occurred when I tested on another pc, the error code is:
Error in supplied FMU: FMU block ... cannot parse XML attribute 'needsExecutionTool' or its contents 'false' for XML element 'fmiModelDescription' in modelDescription.xml file at line 9,column 40. Simulink ignores this attribute and continues.
Error in supplied FMU: An error occurred in function 'fmi2SetupExperiment' for block ... during simulation.
I checked the FMU log file there was no error code.

The strange thing is this fmu can work on one pc, but not on another one, I would appreciate if anyone can provide any help!

Also on this pc, I tried to import the fmu file into dSPACE ConfigurationDesk, and it also showed warmings and an error.
The warmings are:
An error occurred while validating the model description file: The 'needs ExecutionTool' attribute is not declared.
The model description file of the FMU does not comply with the FMI 2.0 standard for co-simulation and might cause problems.
And the model error is: No source code and no supported library available.
The strange thing is this fmu can work on one pc, but not on another one, I would appreciate if anyone can provide any help!

Answer (score 0):

From the error messages, most probably the modelDescription.xml of the FMU is corrupt.
Please check the FMU with one of the valadation tools listed on https://fmi-standard.org/validation/ and/or the FMU compliance checker (https://github.com/modelica-tools/FMUComplianceChecker).
If the validation fails, please contact the tool vendor of the exporting tool.

(FMUs exported from GT require a GT runtime license. The problem that the FMU runs on one PC and not on another could be related to this problem.